# Why an argument can be outside of ( ) in a function definition?

Tags: gcc, arguments, clang, function-prototypes

I have a piece of code in my .y file as follows

```
void yyerror(s) char *s; {
  fputs(s, stderr);
  putc('\n', stderr);
}
```

The function prototype declaration is in another file as follows

```
void yyerror (char const *s);
```

I tried to compile the code on both Linux and mac. On Linux, the compiler generates the following error message

```
error: argument ‘s’ doesn’t match prototype
 void yyerror(s) char *s; {
                       ^
```

On mac, the compiler generates the following warning message

```
warning: promoted type 'char *' of K&R function parameter is not compatible with the parameter type 'const char *' declared in a previous prototype [-Wknr-promoted-parameter]
void yyerror(s) char *s; {
                      ^
```

My questions are:

1. Why clang only generates warning while cc generates an error.
2. Both compilers complain about 's' in "char *s". Why they ignore the 's' in () but consider the second 's' as the argument?

Comment: This was the C language's original style for function parameters,  ANSI C changed it to the style you are more familiar with, the old style is now known as "K&R style". The code is incorrect and the error message explains why; you will need to either change prototype to `char *s` or change the definition to `char const *s` (either K&R style or prototype style)

Comment: @M.M This should be an answer.